# Can someone give reasons as to why the Gods and Rishis often discharged their semen after being overcome by lust?

Tags: mahabharata, brahma, shiva-purana, apsaras, brahma-vaivarta-purana

I saw many refrences regarding gods and rishis "dropping their semen" after seeing another godess or an apsara. How is this justified? Aren't they supposed to follow brahmacharya? Or was it not under their control and was "niyati"?

***Brahma***

Lord Brahma's semen fell after looking at Devi Parvati:

*Shiva Purana, Rudra Samhita 2, Sati Khanda 2, chapter 19, verses 26-28*

”Then, O sage, afflicted by the cupid and delighted in the heart of hearts, I [Brahma] lifted her veil and stared into the face of Sati. I looked at the face of Sati many a time. **I was helpless in curbing the onset of a sensuous organism. Four drops of my semen virile got displaced and fell on the ground like drops of dew as a result of staring into her face.”**

This is also supported by *Brahma Purana Gautami-Mahatmya 3.15*

Brahma is said to have ejaculated on seeing the wives of gods, Apsaras, and other women:

*Vayu Purana, Part 2, 4.29-31*

”The brilliantly shining goddess Earth, the quarters, the intermediate quarters, the Lords of quarters, the celestial virgins, the wives of Devas, the mothers and Ayu all these were present there in embodied form **in front of the Lord (Brahma)** who was performing the Yajna assuming the form of Varuna. **On seeing the ladies, the semen virile of Svayambhu fell on the ground…”**

Brahma discharged his semen after looking at Godess Rati (though this is said to be an effect of arrows, but if it is so, then how come the self-realized god, be overcome by feelings of "Kama"?)

*Brahma Vaivarta Purana, Brahma Khanda 11-20*

”This Khma who wields the following arrows, namely, killing. stupifying, soporific, emaciating and maddening, experimentally discharged the arrrows on all and, at the desire of the Supreme Being every one was excited with lust. To crown all, the great anchorite, **Brahma looked with wistful eyes at Rati and immediately his semen was discharged…”**

Brahma is said to have ejaculated seeing Amogha, the wife of sage Santanu

*Padma Purana Section 1 Sṛṣṭi-khaṇḍa, Chapter 55, verses 16b-18a.*

**“The grandsire of all the worlds, after seeing Amoghā, ejaculated.** From that is said to be the rise of Lauhitya. It purifies all people. It is full of all sacred places; resorting to which a man goes to the healthy world of Brahmā.”

Brahma had again ejaculated on seeing a nymph,

*Brahma Vaivarta Purana, Krishna Janma Khanda 131.2-10*

"Subsequently at that place nymphs who had sprung out of the body of Visnu and who were the digits of Visnu began to dance and chant Visnu’s hymns in a melodious tone. *The paternal grandfather Brahma, observing their hard buttocks, thick spherical breasts and smiling lotus faces, was excited with passion.* **He could not control his heart; his semen was discharged; and out of shame he concealed it on the ground with his cloth.** O Saunaka, after the music was over, he threw the semen along with the cloth rendered hot by lust into the sea of milk.”

***Agni***

*Brahma Vaivarta Purana, Krishna Janma Khanda 131.34-38*

"Once upon a time, all the gods having assembled in the council of the gods, the celestial whores busied themselves with dancing and singing. **On that occasion, the fire-god (having seen Rambha with graceful buttocks), was excited with passion and discharged his semen…”**

***Mitra and Varuna***

Mitra and Varuna are said to have ejaculated on seeing Apsara Urvashi,

*Srimad Bhagavatam 6.18.6*

**”Upon seeing Urvasi, the celestial society girl, both Mitra and Varuṇa discharged semen, which they preserved in an earthen pot. The two sons Agastya and Vasiṣṭha later appeared from that pot, and they are therefore the common sons of Mitra and Varuṇa.** Mitra begot three sons in the womb of his wife, whose name was Revatī. Their names were Utsarga, Ariṣṭa and Pippala.”

This story is also supported by *Rig Veda 7.33.1 and Nirukta 5.13.*

***Rishis***

To avoid making this already long question even lengthier, I'll just write in short as to what happened in those verses. Please correct me if my interpretation is wrong.

*Mahabharata 1.131.1-9*

Old Rishi Bhardwaja ejaculated
seeing wet hairs and disheveled dress of Apsara Ghritachi
on the banks of Ganga while performing ablution.

*Mahabharata 3.110.34-35*

Rishi Vibhandaka ejaculated
seeing Apsara Urvashi near a lake.

*Mahabharata 9.51.5-9*

Rishi Dadicha was performing
penance on the banks of Saraswati river where he saw a beautiful Apsara Alambusa and seeing her the Rishi Dadhicha ejaculated.

*Mahbharata bk 9, section 38*

Rishi Mankana the son of Rishi Kashyapa ejaculated while spotting Apsara Rambha when both were taking bath in Saraswati river.

There are so many more references of Rishis discharging their semen and from then sons being born. But my question is, those rishis that are following brahmacharya, well read in the Vedas, how could they not control their senses? Is it that the apsaras were irresistable? That they simply couldn't help it like some sort of divine force was at play or something else? We can understand that the story of Lord Shiva dropping his semen was a divine Leela, but are these *leelas* as well? It's been written in some Dharmashastras and Puranas that discharging semen was a sin and one goes in hell (Devi Bhagavatam) or one has to do Pashchyataap (Parashara Samhiti). Then why did the rishis and the gods give in to their "*indriya*"? Why did the self-realized god who is a direct manifestation of the Supreme Brahman, be overcome with lust? Kindly explain this in detail as I have many doubts regarding this. Please give all possible context regarding this, previous karma, divine order etc.

Comment: Just one word:prakshipt

Comment: @Hope what does that mean?

Comment: @SuradoeUchiha it means any interpolations, changes etc. In texts (it was done for two reasons:one by fake pandits to get money benefits or to make some ritual to benefit them and other was by islamic invaders and Christian missionaries to defame our religion) . For an entire prakshipt text search allhopanishad Or another Manusmriti (Chapter 5 / Verse 30) is prakshipt if you consider manu 5.50 to 5.52.generally any scripture part or subparts that goes against vedas can be considered prakshipt. To know more https://www.jiva.org/interpolations-of-brahma-vaivarta-pura%E1%B9%87a/

Answer (score 0):

In short, the answer is Brahmā's boon to Kāmadeva. This episode is described in the Kālikā Purāṇa, which is one of the 18 Upapurāṇas. (The list of Upapurāṇas is mentioned in both Kūrma Purāṇa and Devi Bhagavata Purāṇa).

## Kālikā Purāṇa Chapter 1

After creating Prajāpatis and other mind-born sons (Mānasputras), Brahmā created a woman named Sandhya. Then Kāmadeva was created. He was a handsome male equipped with a flowery bow and five arrows made of flowers. He had a flag decorated with a fish and Makara as a mount.

> O the best of the sages! While Brahmā had been thus musing, there appeared, all of a sudden, a male (puruṣa) before them, from the mind of Brahmā. 1.42

> The male (puruṣa) said: O Brahman! What duty should I perform? Be pleased to assign me such work which is just and dignified and worthy of me. 1.50

> Hearing all these queries by that noble person the Creator became surprised at his own creation and remained silent for a while. 1.52

> Then mastering control over his mind and thus making himself free from the state of surprise Brahmā commenced speaking recounting his duties. 1.53

Brahmā said:

> With this exceedingly handsome figure of yours and by using these five flowery arrows! (O Puruṣa) **do enchant the entire males and females and do engage yourself in eternal creation.** 1.54

> **The gods(deva)**, gandharvas, kinnaras, the great serpents (uraga), asuras, daityas, vidyādharas, rākṣasas, yakṣas, piśācas, bhūtas, vināyakas, guhyakas, **siddhas, the human beings**, the birds, the animals, the deer, the worms, the insects and those born of water-there shall be **none who shall not fall a victim of thy arrows**. 1.55-57

> **Whether it is me or Vāsudeva or Śiva or Puruṣottama-all of us shall be completely under your influence, what to speak of other living beings.** Always entering into the heart of all the living beings invisibly, being yourself the source of happiness in their mind, you **do engage yourself in the eternal creation**. 1.58-59

Thus, you see that no one is safe from his flowery arrows, not even Devas and Siddhas! To maintain the creation Brahmā gave that much power to Kāmadeva.

Reference -

[Kalika Purāṇa translated into English by B. N. Shastry](https://archive.org/details/QCML_the-kalika-puran-translated-in-english-by-b-n-shastri-edited-by-surendra-pratap-nag-publishers-/page/n45/mode/2up)